# A question about the Euler characteristic

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $G$ be a finite group acting freely on a compact and orientable Riemannian manifold of dimension 2. I want to show that $\chi(M/ G)=\frac{\chi(M)}{|G|}$, where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic, just using techniques in the scope of "elementary" Riemannian Geometry. I thought about Gauss-Bonnet Theorem, but I'm not able to use it properly. Can you help me ?
Thank you.

Comment: If you define $\chi$ via triangulations: The inverse image of a triangulation of $M/G$ turns out to be a triangulation of $M$ with $|G|$ times as many vertices, egdes, faces and  so on.

Comment: One more thing: Every smooth manifold admits a triangulation. In the topological category, the result still holds but is harder to prove.